# Prevent entering any additional characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm using this [Angular Directive](https://gist.github.com/aberke/042eef0f37dba1138f9e) to format phone numbers in an input to `(999) 999-9999`. This works great until a user makes a mistake and modifies the entered phone number.

You can replicate this issue by running the code below and doing the following:

• Enter the phone number `(555) 123-4567`
• Place your cursor after the `4` character and delete it.
• Type in `0` twice.

You can see that the `0` is added twice and the `7` character is dropped.

Another issue is if a user attempts to delete and change the `1` character. Their cursor is pushed to the very end of the input.

I'm sure this is due to an issue with the phonenumber filter, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

```js
function MyCntl($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = {};
    $scope.myPrompt = "Input your phonenumber here!";
}

var phonenumberModule = angular.module('phonenumberModule', [])
 
 .directive('phonenumberDirective', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  /*
  Intended use:
   <phonenumber-directive placeholder='prompt' model='someModel.phonenumber'></phonenumber-directive>
  Where:
   someModel.phonenumber: {String} value which to bind only the numeric characters [0-9] entered
    ie, if user enters 617-2223333, value of 6172223333 will be bound to model
   prompt: {String} text to keep in placeholder when no numeric input entered
  */
 
  function link(scope, element, attributes) {
 
   // scope.inputValue is the value of input element used in template
   scope.inputValue = scope.phonenumberModel;
 
   scope.$watch('inputValue', function(value, oldValue) {
    
    value = String(value);
    var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    scope.phonenumberModel = number;
    scope.inputValue = $filter('phonenumber')(number);
   });
  }
  
  return {
   link: link,
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
    phonenumberPlaceholder: '=placeholder',
    phonenumberModel: '=model',
   },
   //templateUrl: '/static/phonenumberModule/template.html',
   
            template: '<input name="phonenumber" ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" class="phonenumber" placeholder="{{phonenumberPlaceholder}}" title="Phonenumber (Format: (999) 9999-9999)">',
  };
 }])
 
 .filter('phonenumber', function() {
     /* 
     Format phonenumber as: c (xxx) xxx-xxxx
      or as close as possible if phonenumber length is not 10
      if c is not '1' (country code not USA), does not use country code
     */
     
     return function (number) {
      /* 
      @param {Number | String} number - Number that will be formatted as telephone number
      Returns formatted number: (###) ###-####
       if number.length < 4: ###
       else if number.length < 7: (###) ###
 
      Does not handle country codes that are not '1' (USA)
      */
         if (!number) { return ''; }
 
         number = String(number);
 
         // Will return formattedNumber. 
         // If phonenumber isn't longer than an area code, just show number
         var formattedNumber = number;
 
   // if the first character is '1', strip it out and add it back
   var c = (number[0] == '1') ? '1 ' : '';
   number = number[0] == '1' ? number.slice(1) : number;
 
   // # (###) ###-#### as c (area) front-end
   var area = number.substring(0,3);
   var front = number.substring(3, 6);
   var end = number.substring(6, 10);
 
   if (front) {
    formattedNumber = (c + "(" + area + ") " + front); 
   }
   if (end) {
    formattedNumber += ("-" + end);
   }
   return formattedNumber;
     };
 });
```

```css
.phonenumber {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="phonenumberModule" ng-controller="MyCntl">
    <p>phonenumber value: {{ myModel.phonenumber }}</p>
    <p>formatted phonenumber: {{ myModel.phonenumber | phonenumber }}</p>
    <form name="phoneForm">
        <phonenumber-directive placeholder="myPrompt" model='myModel.phonenumber'></phonenumber-directive>
        <div ng-show="phoneForm.phonenumber.$error.minlength">
          <p>Enter a valid phone number</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try to fix that?

Comment: `ng-show="phoneForm.phonenumber.$error.minlength)"` That last parenthesis throws an error.

Comment: @spenibus Fixed. Although wasn't the cause of my issue. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: If you really want this behavior then you need to proceed key events, copy-past event, drag-drop event manually. (I.e. do not let input change when user types letter - then cursor will stand in place). However, I think that more user-friendly is to let user type whatever he wants - and show validation error.

Comment: What type of functionality are you looking for here or you just looking for a reason.  By default it is being evaluated on every key stoke and it is just truncating the length of the input at this point  var end = number.substring(6, 10);

Comment: As for the Cursor jumping on trying to delete the one from what I can tell that only happens when you try to backspace the formatting space you applied.  You can delete the 1 if the cursor is in front or if the cursor is directly behind.  I would put that on the filter resetting the cursor to a valid place because you just tried to delete a formatting in the filter.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying a user's input as they type can be distracting and always leads to problems like those you describe.

In general, it is easier to implement and less frustrating to the user to modify the UI instead. A common solution for the case of phone numbers is to put three input fields side-by-side, with the formatting characters displayed in-between.

Using Angular, a single directive can be created to wrap this multi-part input mechanism and expose a single concatenated result to the rest of the app.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use an editable field (like input of type text) to enter the number and a read-only field (like a label) to show it formatted, because the formatted value is just a display concern, so it should not be editable.

So I modified your snippet to do that.

```js
function MyCntl($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = {};
    $scope.myPrompt = "Input your phonenumber here!";
}

var phonenumberModule = angular.module('phonenumberModule', [])
 
 .directive('phonenumberDirective', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  /*
  Intended use:
   <phonenumber-directive placeholder='prompt' model='someModel.phonenumber'></phonenumber-directive>
  Where:
   someModel.phonenumber: {String} value which to bind only the numeric characters [0-9] entered
    ie, if user enters 617-2223333, value of 6172223333 will be bound to model
   prompt: {String} text to keep in placeholder when no numeric input entered
  */
 
  function link(scope, element, attributes) {
 
   // scope.inputValue is the value of input element used in template
   scope.inputValue = scope.phonenumberModel;
 
   scope.$watch('inputValue', function(value, oldValue) {
    
    value = String(value);
                oldValue = String(oldValue);
                // get rid of input non digits chars
    var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                var oldNumber = oldValue.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    
                var filteredNumber = $filter('phonenumber')(number);
                // get rid of filter non digits chars
                scope.phonenumberModel = filteredNumber.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                inputValue = scope.phonenumberModel;
                var filteredOldNumber = $filter('phonenumber')(oldNumber);
                if(filteredNumber.length === filteredOldNumber.length) {
                    scope.maxlength = filteredNumber.length;
                }
                else {
                    scope.maxlength = Math.max(number.length, 11);
                }                    
   });
  }
  
  return {
   link: link,
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
    phonenumberPlaceholder: '=placeholder',
    phonenumberModel: '=model',
   },
   //templateUrl: '/static/phonenumberModule/template.html',
   
            template: '<input name="phonenumber" ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" maxlength="{{maxlength || 11}}" class="phonenumber" placeholder="{{phonenumberPlaceholder}}" title="Phonenumber (Format: (999) 9999-9999)"> <label>Formatted:{{inputValue | phonenumber}}</label>',
  };
 }])
 
 .filter('phonenumber', function() {
     /* 
     Format phonenumber as: c (xxx) xxx-xxxx
      or as close as possible if phonenumber length is not 10
      if c is not '1' (country code not USA), does not use country code
     */
     
     return function (number) {
      /* 
      @param {Number | String} number - Number that will be formatted as telephone number
      Returns formatted number: (###) ###-####
       if number.length < 4: ###
       else if number.length < 7: (###) ###
 
      Does not handle country codes that are not '1' (USA)
      */
         if (!number) { return ''; }
 
         number = String(number);
 
         // Will return formattedNumber. 
         // If phonenumber isn't longer than an area code, just show number
         var formattedNumber = number;
 
   // if the first character is '1', strip it out and add it back
   var c = (number[0] == '1') ? '1 ' : '';
   number = number[0] == '1' ? number.slice(1) : number;
 
   // # (###) ###-#### as c (area) front-end
   var area = number.substring(0,3);
   var front = number.substring(3, 6);
   var end = number.substring(6, 10);
 
   if (front) {
    formattedNumber = (c + "(" + area + ") " + front); 
   }
   if (end) {
    formattedNumber += ("-" + end);
   }
   return formattedNumber;
     };
 });
```

```css
.phonenumber {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="phonenumberModule" ng-controller="MyCntl">
    <p>phonenumber value: {{ myModel.phonenumber }}</p>
    <p>formatted phonenumber: {{ myModel.phonenumber | phonenumber }}</p>
    <form name="phoneForm">
        <phonenumber-directive placeholder="myPrompt" model='myModel.phonenumber'></phonenumber-directive>
        <div ng-show="phoneForm.phonenumber.$error.minlength">
          <p>Enter a valid phone number</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check plunker  please ...  i hope this is what u want ..

http://plnkr.co/edit/0IBJBRb2JtvZnq6PtBiV?p=preview

supporting masking and regex .. (is beta) 
Usage : # for both ,   a for chars  , 9 is for numbers ... 
( mask filter is not working as accepted will  check it ..

```
 <maskinput ng-mask-model="value" ng-mask="9 (999) 99-9999" ng-mask-regex="[^0-9]+"></maskinput>
```

Comment: have to work on keypress  to fix bugs with switch ... i dunno which ones user need to fix ..  bugs can be fixed .. main problems are getting and setting cursor position  and it is fixed .. i can't do all fixes ..

Comment: You can't rely on 0/4 positions, because there is `1 (234) 567-8900` format

Comment: as i describe before ..  be fixed on keypress .. user have to validate .. as i wrote   comments  on keypress if you check the all code  ...  /*
   you have to check keys arrow back , delete , backspace, arrow forward  
    use these witch switch  what you need 
  */ and  // here is the barracks and space of your mask you have to check

Comment: you have to understand i am just simplizied the way ..  writing alll code never gives the  user to learn something ..